# Tensorflow : how to get a list of checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to programatically get a list of existing checkpoints that does not rely on directory listing and file exension validation, if you type:

```
tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('checkpoints')
```

You can see printed this list, but i cant find a way to capture this printed list so it can be iterated later , is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do:

```
tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('checkpoints').all_model_checkpoint_paths
```

This will give you the list of checkpoint paths. The CheckpointState protobuf is defined at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/checkpoint_state.proto

Answer (score 0):

There is a `checkpoint` file under the `tf.Saver()` specified python, it contains last n available checkpoints file, such as:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "model.ckpt-43083927"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-43083669"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-43083764"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-43083925"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-43083926"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "model.ckpt-43083927"
```

Comment: Interestingly in my case there's always the latest checkpoint listed..